# give positions for sphere drawn using gluSphere()

Tags: c, opengl, glu

Here's my code .. But my sphere always stays at the origin... my glTranslatef() doesn't change the position of the sphere... Give me answers with explanation..

```c
glColor3f(1,0,0);
GLUquadric *quad;
quad = gluNewQuadric();
gluSphere(quad,25,100,20);
glTranslatef(2,2,2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're drawing the sphere before doing the translation, so of course the translation has no effect.

Move your `glTranslatef` to above `gluSphere`

```c
glColor3f(1,0,0);
GLUquadric *quad;
quad = gluNewQuadric();
glTranslatef(2,2,2);
gluSphere(quad,25,100,20);
```

(Also note that the `glu` library is a quite old, and you should probably avoid it)

Comment: @Packirisamy Also, while you're at it, try reading up on hierarchical modelling to prevent such issues in the future.